# Send JS commands to browser tab

Tags: java, javascript, c#, google-chrome

I want to send a command to my browser, let's say chrome.

For example, I use a website which has a really neat audio player, i know this audioplayer has a javascript function called    `prevTrack()` and `nextTrack()` etc etc etc.... what i wan't to do is to create a program (in java/c#) that would go into the browser console and send that command, if for example, I hit some kind of hotkey "ctrl + n" for example.

Is there any way to manipulate chrome like that?

Thanks

Comment: WebSockets, learn about them.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol

Comment: Make a chrome extension which interacts the tabs via `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. Use a Websocket connection to interface with the extension and forward commands.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an application which incorporates the browser into Java using something like http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html - it can open a browser window, navigate to a location, and then execute arbitrary Javascript.